# Docker container stats in cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using the Amazon AWS free tier for a proof of concept. I have docker running on a EC2 instance with a few containers. I'm aware you can run some scripts to monitor the memory of the EC2 instance but was wondering if there were scripts available to monitor the CPU/memory of each of the docker containers and send the results to CloudWatch.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use weave-scope [link](https://github.com/weaveworks/scope). It is a very nice tool to monitor any docker container.

Answer (score 0):

After looking for options. I didn't find any specific solution for shipping container level stats to cloud watch.

Nonetheless, you can reuse the [Aws mon scripts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html) and parse the command docker stats, roughly something like this drift:

```
docker ps | tail -n +2 > dockerps.txt #all lines except the firts one.
running_containers = cat dockerps.txt | wc -l
for (i=0;i=running_containers;i++) {
    container_id = cat dockerps.txt |  tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f1 | sed -n -e $ip
    image_name = cat dockerps.txt |  tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f2 | sed -n -e $ip
    used_mem = docker stats --no-stream | grep $(cat dockerps.txt |  tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f1 |  sed -n -e 3p) |  tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3
    #and now send it to cloudwatch using the mon script 
}
```

Or go for [cAdvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor) + [prometheus.io](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/installation/) + [Grafana](https://grafana.com/grafana) (its what I am doing)

To track the memory use by a specific container, for example, celery. I am running this every minute (with crontab):

```
docker ps | tail -n +2 > dockerps.txt
(echo -n  $(date)" " && docker stats --no-stream | grep $(cat dockerps.txt | grep celery |  tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f1 ) |  tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3)
```

and then filebeat is shipping all the outputs to elasticsearch cluster where I have a graphic for this value, also a grok in logstash is necesary to parse it. Or you can ship it to prometheus.

I hope this helps somebody

Comment: may i know what to do in  `#and now send it to cloudwatch using the mon script` ?

Comment: To get utilization statistics for the last 12 hours, run the following command:
./mon-get-instance-stats.pl --recent-hours=12
For more info, please read the AWS mon scripts link in the answer :)